# If command to look at specific lines and value in files

Tags: command-line

I imagine this is a very simple one but I'm really new to Ubuntu. I basically want to command ubuntu to look through files with a certain suffix (QC.fastq.log) and to then look at a value on line 3 in bracket and then if that is higher than 0.1 to then complete another command.

So I've this

```
for file in *QC.fastq.log

Do

If [ -e $file ] # this is where I thing the line and bracket command should be

then 

the next command
```

Any ideas?

An example file:

```
6882 reads; of these:
  6882 (100.00%) were unpaired; of these:
    1088 (15.81%) aligned 0 times
    5792 (84.16%) aligned exactly 1 time
    2 (0.03%) aligned >1 times
84.19% overall alignment rate
```

Comment: An example of the input file would be helpful (especially the third line!). If you could [edit] that into  your question it'd be appreciated.

Comment: Not entirely sure on how to stick a file on here

Comment: Not sure if it's just typos in the question, but your `do` and `if` should not have capital letters.

Comment: 1088 (15.81%) aligned 0 times #line 3, I'm interested in the value in brackets. ie if that is over 0.1% then proceed to next command.

Comment: in python, this is very simple, or I must be missing something. Is python an option?

Answer (score 1):

Those are some a pretty hardcore requirements!
If you can cope with just matching anything bigger than 0.09, this should work:

```
find -name '*QC.fastq.log' -exec sh -c 'sed -n 3p {} && grep -q \(0.0 || echo "DO SOMETHING"' \;
```

- For any file that matches the glob
- Get the third line with `sed`
- If that DOESN'T (`||`) match `(0.0` (that will only ever be under 0.1),
- Run the command.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a little shell script doing the job:

```
filemask="*QC.fastq.log"

while read -r -d $'\0' file
do
  if [ "$(echo "$(sed -nr "3s/^.*\((.*)%\).*$/\1/p}" "${file}") > 0.1" | bc)" = "1" ]
  then
    echo "${file}" is greater 0.1
  fi
done < <(find . -name "${filemask}" -print0)
```

Comment: ty, it's always a good idea to quote any variable expansion - I dont know why I miss it again and again.